# Meaning of "Abgechecktheit"

Tags: german-to-english, meaning, slang

I am reading an interview with Cro from Die Zeit [here](http://www.zeit.de/kultur/musik/2014-06/rapper-cro-hip-hop).

At the beginning (yeah already stuck! lol):

> Frage: Cro, kürzlich bei Ihrer Album-Präsentation haben Sie gesagt: "Ich bin der schlechteste Erwachsene der Welt." Wieso?
>
> Cro: Wenn ich das auf meine Abgechecktheit beziehe …

I haven't been able to find the meaning of "Abgechecktheit" anywhere. I've even looked in reputable dictionaries that have been suggested to me – [LEO](http://www.leo.org/index_de.html). I have also asked a native speaker and she didn't even know, suggesting it might be of a particular dialect.

Comment: The interviewer and I haven't heard that either. However, Cro's explaining the meaning on request in the next sentence.

Comment: ohhh good point I didn't even notice that, in the context, she even asks him what that means...

Comment: now that you know, you can write an answer to your question, so we know too :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He explains this as his childishness and his freedom to be childish. He mentions that he can do the grown up stuff when push comes to shove, but he claims that he has close to no control of his own life, his examples are him not sitting straight on chairs and him not using the polite way to address people ("Sie" instead of "Du"). He can relax, let go and have fun and that makes up his "Abgechecktheit".

As for the origin, "etwas checken" can be used as a slang variant of "etwas verstehen" which means understanding stuff. "Lass uns mal das Kino-Angebot abchecken" refers to the verb "etwas abchecken" which can translate to "to check something out", for my example it's "Let's check out what's running in the cinema".

As you have guessed already, this is not ever used oficially (thus not part of LEO translations) and is personal slang. Since Cro is a rapper, he obviously has his own slang language. If you should ever use this word to a normal German you will have to explain that word just as Cro had to.

P.S.: It's "Die Zeit" and not "Der Zeit". :)

Comment: Ganz im Gegenteil. "Ich bin der schlechteste Erwachsene der Welt." hat er gesagt und erklärt "ich beziehe das auf meine Abgechecktheit", sprich, er ist schlecht abgecheckt. "Na ja, das Leben nicht im Griff zu haben." Erwachsene haben das Leben im Griff - er nicht. Abgechecktheit ist ein Attribut von Erwachsenen, die so sind wie er gerade nicht ist.

Comment: Erstens würde ich bei englischen Fragen immer auf Englisch antworten, genauso würde ich bei englischen Antworten immer auf englisch antworten.

Comment: Zweitens bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob Abgechecktheit in diesem Fall die geistige Reife beschreibt oder die Möglichkeit, sich komplett auszuklinken und das Leben zu genießen wie es Kinder tun. Wenn er häufiger "abgecheckt" ist, würde er den Mangel an Erwachsensein auch auf die Abgechecktheit beziehen, denn diese hindert ihn dann, den nötigen Ernst aufzubringen. Sicher bin ich mir hierbei nicht, aber ich denke, da er sich das Wort im Prinzip selbst ausgedacht hat, weiß nur er wirklich, was damit gemeint ist. Meine Antwort legte stark Wert darauf, dass diese Wort normalerweise nicht benutzt wird.

Answer (score 6):

I could imagine that this (made up) word is based on colloquial youth slang "etwas [checken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/checken)" or "ein [Checker](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Checker) sein", meaning to understand things, in this case life in general.

EDIT At least those were used when I was younger - definitely too long ago...

Comment: Sprachlich hätte er dann aber sagen müssen "mein Abcheckertum". Die Vorsilbe 'ge-' bringt ja Passivität ins Spiel "ich bin/wurde abgebrüht" kann man sagen. "Ich bin abgecheckt" würde man sagen, wenn man am Flughafen oder der Disko zum 2. Mal kontrolliert werden soll. Die Wortbildung ist total verunglückt und wird durch das "~heit" auch nicht mehr gerettet.

Comment: Ja, ich weiß auch nicht, wieso ein gelernter Mediengestalter und Rapper in den Promo-Interviews für sein neues Album nicht mehr auf sprachwissenschaftliche Details achtet...

Comment: Es geht nicht um sprachwissenschaftliche Details sondern um sprachliche Details, um Dich auf dieses Detail hinzuweisen. Falls es Dich interessiert, dann könnte ich Dir verraten, dass ein Grund, mehr auf die Sprache zu achten, wäre, dass man von der Zeitungstante und den Leuten hier auf Anhieb verstanden wird, und nicht so uncool wie ein funktionaler Analphabet herüberkommmt, der sich nicht verständlich ausdrücken kann. Es muss Dich aber nicht interessieren. Wenn es Dich anödet, dann verhalte Dich doch einfach ignorant gegenüber dem Thema.

Comment: Kein Grund, pampig zu werden. Die Frage des Nicht-Muttersprachlers war, was das Wort bedeutet bzw. woher es kommen könnte - das habe ich beantwortet (siehe 6 Up-Votes). Deine Analyse halte ich nicht für falsch, aber für übertrieben, da es sich einfach nur einen aus der Interview-Situation heraus erfundenen Begriff handelt.

Comment: Vielleicht habe ich Deinen Kommentar zuvor falsch aufgefasst; dieser kam für mich belehrend, schnippisch und von oben herab rüber - was kein Problem gewesen wäre, wenn er inhaltlich die Belehrung enthalten hätte, die der Ton versprach. Inhaltlich wurde jedoch nur ein Appell an die Autorität des gelernten Medienschaffenden aufgefahren. Womöglich habe ich da eine Ironie überlesen? So oder so ist die Frage, was das Wort bedeutet ernsthaft gestellt worden und bedarf einer ernsthaften Antwort. Da ist ja niemandem gedient wenn ich dem Sprecher übertriebenen Respekt erweise.

Answer (score 2):

Aus dem Zeitinterview ergibt sich, dass er etwas meint, dass sich nicht analytisch aus den Wortbetstandteilen ableiten lässt.

Man kennt Abgeschmacktheit oder Abgebrühtsein, aber Abgechecktheit?

Er erklärt es denn auch der rätselnden Interviewerin. Er sagt, er sei ein schlechter Erwachsener, und diese seien Abgecheckt. Seine Abgechecktheit ist also schlecht oder gering. Es ist nicht seine Eigenschaft sondern die der Anderen.

Das Leben planen ist, was ein Abchecker macht. Das macht er nur bei wichtigen Plattenverträgen - im Alltag lässt er der Spontaneität freien Lauf.

Ich würde sagen er meint eine Mischung aus Konformismus und verplant sein.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, no-one so far has connected this with "[Abgeklärtheit](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Abgeklaertheit)", which to me seems the most obvious source for this.

Cro appears to have heard the word at some point, without fully understanding it, and then have tried to form something that sounds vaguely like it, using his usual (Denglish) vocabulary.

The context makes it clear that he means "being adult".

NON-NATIVES: This is *not* a German word and should best be forgotten altogether; its formation is unidiomatic and it makes this guy sound like a stereotypical German rapper who's unfortunately not very bright.

Comment: It most certainly IS a German word and very idiomatic, just one that is part of youth slang rather than mainstream culture.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: As a native speaker, you're of course free to use this expression. I just don't think it's a good idea not to warn non-natives that it is slang. Since this site is not the German equivalent of urban dictionary but strives to provide useful advice for general usage rather than definitions of newly coined slang expressions, I may have come across a bit judgemental - but I still think it was justified. Also note that googling "Abgechecktheit" exclusively yields links to either this particular interview, comments on it, or this question - not a single other occurrence.

Comment: While this guy may have been the first who thought of adding the -heit suffix, "abgecheckt" is even in the Duden.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Okay, a bit confused now... none of the three Duden definitions of "abchecken" fits the context here - so the relationship seems to me tentative at best. "Checken" is a much more likely candidate. My point is that non-natives will run a very high risk of not being understood if they use "Abgechecktheit". It complicates things instead of helping communication.